# AngularJS difference in dependency requirement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependencies

Hi I'm learing AngularJS and I was wondering what the difference is of defining your dependencies:

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    // stuff
}]);
```

vs:

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    // stuff
});
```

Just wondering what the difference is :)

Comment: The first format is to support minification. Please read documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that the second option will break if you minify your JavaScript.

As suggest by Maxim Shoustin and Chandermani, here's some more detailed information:

http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications/
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di